# How to read big nested Json and fetch a repetitive key value using Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

Hi I am trying to read a very complicated nested Json of following structure and need to fetch all label values and store in a list. I tried many approaches but I am not successful .Can you please help me on this.I have tried below code .but not able to fetch the details

```html
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    if (key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("labels")) {
                        Strin val = json.get(key).toString();
                    System.out.println(val);

                    }

                }
```

```
{
   "expand":"schema,names",
   "total":142,
   "issues":[
      {
         "id":"10220951",
            "fields":{
     "labels": [
                "Test"
            ]
}}{
     "id":"10220952",
        "fields":{
     "labels": [
                "Test2"
            ]
}}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and the problems you had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 solutions, you can choose one of them.

1.Use JsonPath of Rest-Assured

```
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

List<List<String>> allLabels = JsonPath.from(jsonString).getList("issues.fields.labels");

List<String> labels = allLabels.stream()
               .flatMap(Collection::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(labels);
//[Test, Test2]
```

2.Use JsonPath of jayway

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

List<List<String>> allLabels = JsonPath.read(res, "$..labels");

List<String> labels = allLabels.stream()
               .flatMap(Collection::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(labels);
//[Test, Test2]
```